# How to Safely set Expire in Redis Client?

Tags: javascript, redis, ioredis

I got in weird trouble, I have to set key expire in `redis` after given milliseconds. No issue after few works i did following:

```
Client.expire(_id, expireSeconds)
```

Now expire which redis support is in Seconds now whole Project on which currently I am working in uses MilliSecond library short MS(https://www.npmjs.com/package/milliseconds).

How can I safely convert every milliseconds into Seconds which redis client can support?

Note:

```
...
expire/60000 <--- for getting minutes
...
```

Suppose if client got request for key to expire in 15s than getting in minutes format it will be like 0.14 which redis client don't support [out of range error will occur]. Please could anyone help me with something that could convert milliseconds to seconds with redundancy to maintain time on which key has to expire.

Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Why are you talking about converting to minutes?

Comment: 15 seconds are 15000 milliseconds. what is the issue?

Comment: issue is MS Library...in which you define 15s as Ms('15s') now it returns 10000 now its in ms now Redis.expire think that i am talking about 10000 seconds instead 15s

Comment: and do note that we can use .set() or PX flag...need something around .expire()

Comment: You can set it in milliseconds with https://redis.io/commands/pexpire

Answer (score 1):

USE **PEXPIRE** instead of **EXPIRE**. This command works exact same like **EXPIRE** except that u can configure the time to live of the key in **miliseconds**